# Marketing Cloud Connect: impact of changing or refreshing core Salesforce org

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a connection between Salesforce sandbox and Marketing Cloud instance. There are some journeys configured in Journey Builder. In the documentation I see

> Disconnecting does the following:
>
> - Removes the connection between your Marketing Cloud account and Sales or Service Cloud org.
> - Removes the Salesforce system user’s credentials and resets the connection at the account level.
> - Removes user mappings in the disconnected business unit and synchronized data extensions.
> - Cancels tracking subscriptions. Any tracking for previous sends is not pushed to the previous Sales or Service Cloud org. Tracking is not affected in the Marketing Cloud

I have two questions.
The first question is: Will work my journeys and other configured functionality if I disconnect my Sandbox org, connect Production org and configure synchronized data extensions? Or I need to create all my functionality again?

The second question is: Will work my journeys and other configured functionality if I refresh Sandbox org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your journeys are based on data coming from Synchronised Data Extensions, recreating these and populating appropriate entry Data Extensions will restore the original functionality.

If you are using Salesforce Data Entry Events, you need to recreate the events in a new version of your journey, as these must have triggers configured in the connecting org. If you disconnect from Org A and connect to Org B, the monitored objects will not trigger any of the journeys.

[This article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249278&type=1) lists actions you should take in connection with a sandbox refresh. It doesn't contain info on JB entry events, but these work similar to Trigger Sends (both use triggers in SC)

Comment: Lukas, thanks for the answer! Does it mean that If I refresh Sandbox org I need just create a new version of journey and change/create new entry source? But if I disconnect from Org A and connect to Org B I need to create all journeys from scratch. Is it correct? What else MC functionality will not work after refresh/change org? Could you please propose some steps or best practices before refresh/change orgs?

Comment: You don't have to create journeys from scratch - only recreate the entry event, to ensure the triggers are created in the correct org

Comment: I also added a link to my answer, with more details